# Sidenav broken the app Angular 5 error

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm using **Angular 5 / Material 2 / Flex-Layout** - When I try to add the tag## Heading ## `<mat-sidenav-container>` the page breaks, do not load the remaining content stays and Loading.

Something that is missing? I attach the code:

```html
<div style="height: 20vh;">
    <mat-toolbar role="heading" aria-label="navigation">
        <mat-toolbar-row>
            <nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
                <a mat-tab-link
                   *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
                   [routerLink]="link.path"
                   routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
                   [active]="rla.isActive">
                    {{link.label}}
                </a>
            </nav>
            <!-- Mobile Button Nav -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></span>
            </button>

            <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>
        </mat-toolbar-row>

        <div fxShow="true" fxHide.gt-sm="true">
            <a href="#" (click)="sidenav.open()">Show Side Menu</a>
        </div>

    </mat-toolbar>

    <mat-sidenav-container fxFlexFill class="nav-mobile-container">
        <mat-sidenav #sidenav fxLayout="column">
            <div fxLayout="column">
                <a (click)="sidenav.close()" href="#" mat-button>Close</a>
                <a href="#" mat-button>Menu Item 1</a>
            </div>
        </mat-sidenav>
        <mat-sidenav-content fxFlexFill>Main content</mat-sidenav-content>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
    </div>
```

What I'm trying to do is the responsive navbar for mobile devices.

Attach error on the console:

[image]

Comment: Are you importing the correct module to your app.module? `import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';`

Comment: Please, post your `AppModule` code as well as the version for Angular and Angular Material from your `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

You need import module MatSidenavModule in module.